# how to unselect a select option box after some calculation is done

Tags: jquery

just wondering how it's possible to un-select the select option box, i used .remove() but this actually removes the text from the select box,

is there any other way.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to set the default text as the selected one?

Comment: I have some select boxes, I get their values and text and add them to arrays after that I need to set the to their original state.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$('#mySelectBox :selected').attr('selected', '');`

Where #mySelectBox is the id of your select element.

Answer (score 7):

These cases vary for select boxes with single options and select boxes with multiple options.

For select boxes with single options:

```
<select id='selectbox'>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        $('#selectbox').attr('selectedIndex', '-1');
});
```

Note: you need this variant to make it work in Internet Explorer. The example below also works for single option textboxes in Internet Explorer.

For select boxes with multiple options:

```
<select id='selectbox' multiple='multiple'>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        $('#selectbox option').attr('selected', '');

});
```

Comment: Change "attr('selected', 'false');" to "attr('selected', '');" and you have yourself a great answer...

Answer (score 1):

A VERY delayed response, but I found this works better for a select multiple, so hopefully can help someone else who finds this on Google too.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        $('#selectbox option').removeAttr('selected');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Late answer but I couldn't find anything that worked with a non-multiple select box so I wrote this myself.

```
    var chg = 0; // global to unselect
$("#myoptions").on({
  mousedown : function(){
   chg = 0;
 },
 change : function() {
    chg = 1;
 },
 click: function() {
   if (chg !== 1) {
   $("#myoptions")[0].selectedIndex = -1;
   }
 }
});
```

I tested this in Chrome and IE8.

It will allow you to select and then deselect like you can with the multiple select box. You do not have to use the CTRL key but if you do it still works.

Here is a jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rkekvows/